# How to remove url variable, then replace with new url using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the code below that adds the `lang` variable to a url each time a flag is clicked.  But I need to add an additional piece - I want to remove the previous `lang` variable first, before adding a new one.

Currently my code keeps adding on to the previous url variable.  How can I fix this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("a.flag").on('click',function() {
      var lang_prefix = $(this).attr("title");
      window.location.href = window.location.href + '?lang=' + lang_prefix;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `lang` is the only query parameter you're using...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("a.flag").on('click',function() {
      var lang_prefix = $(this).attr("title");
      window.location.href = window.location.href.split('?')[0] + '?lang=' + lang_prefix;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Great job Oscar.  Thanks for the awesome fast answer.  It works great!